# Type constraint issue with protocol in Swift

Tags: swift

I have a protocol `AProtocol` that has some data structs and a protocol `BProtocol` that has an action which takes parameters conform to `AProtocol`. The code goes like this:

```
protocol AProtocol {
    // data
}

protocol BProtocol {
    func action<T: AProtocol>(completionHandle: (Bool, [T]?) -> ())
}
```

When I implement these protocols - A struct conforms to `AProtocol` and a class conforms to `BProtocol`,   I cannot find a way to satisfy the compiler.

```
struct AStruct: AProtocol {

}

class BClass: BProtocol {
    var structs = [AStruct]()
    func action<T : AProtocol>(completionHandle: (Bool, [T]?) -> ()) {
        completionHandle(true, self.structs) // Compile error: "'AStruct' is not identical to 'T'"
    }
}
```

### Updated:

I tried using type casting, but failed to invoke the `action` with another error("Cannot convert the expression's type '(($T4, ($T4, $T5) -> ($T4, $T5) -> $T3) -> ($T4, ($T4, $T5) -> $T3) -> $T3, (($T4, $T5) -> ($T4, $T5) -> $T3, $T5) -> (($T4, $T5) -> $T3, $T5) -> $T3) -> (($T4, ($T4, $T5) -> $T3) -> $T3, (($T4, $T5) -> $T3, $T5) -> $T3) -> $T3' to type 'AProtocol'"):

```
class BClass: BProtocol {
    var structs = [AStruct]()
    func action<T : AProtocol>(completionHandle: (Bool, [T]?) -> ()) {
        completionHandle(true, self.structs.map({$0 as T})) // Now the compile error has gone
    }

    func testAction() {
        self.action({ // Compile error: "Cannot convert the expression's type..."
            (boolValue, arrayOfStructs) in
            if boolValue {
                // Do something
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I wonder why am I wrong and how to solve the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it with

```
completionHandle(true, self.structs.map { $0 as T })
```

I am not sure whether its a bug or some constraint in the languages that forbids you to directly cast this array. It could be that its not possible because arrays are value types.

To your updated question:
You have specified generic type for action method, so compiler cannot get the type from context. You have to explicitly set it:

```
var bClass = BClass()
bClass.action { (boolValue, arrayOfAProtocol: [AProtocol]?) in
    if boolValue {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It calms down the compiler indeed. But when I try invoking the method `action`, another error arises and it seems have something to do with the type casting, as shown in my updated question.

Comment: There is still a little problem: the `bClass.action { (boolValue, arrayOfAProtocol: [AProtocol]?)` should be `bClass.action { (boolValue, arrayOfAProtocol: [AStruct]?)`

Answer (score 1):

In order for that to work you have to:

- change the `structs` type from `[AStruct]` to `[AProtocol]`
- within the `action` method, explicitly cast `self.structs` to `[T]`

Code:

```
class BClass: BProtocol {
    var structs = [AProtocol]()
    func action<T : AProtocol>(completionHandle: (Bool, [T]?) -> ()) {
        completionHandle(true,  self.structs as? [T])
    }
}
```

The reason is that the `action` method expects **any type** implementing the `AProtocol`. By using `self.structs`, you are forcing it to use `AStruct`.

Let me make an example. Consider you have this struct:

```
struct BStruct: AProtocol {}
```

It implements `AProtocol`, so as per the method definition you should be able to call `action` using that as the generic type. But `BStruct` is not `AStruct` (although they implement the same protocol), so the compiler doesn't know how to cast `[AStruct]` to `[BStruct]`, if that's even possible.

Depending from what's the goal of what you're trying to achieve, you could change your protocol a little bit, by moving the generic type `T` from the method to the protocol/class level:

```
protocol BProtocol {
    typealias DataType
    func action(completionHandle: (Bool, [DataType]?) -> ())
}

class BClass<T: AProtocol>: BProtocol {
    typealias DataType = T

    var structs = [T]()
    func action(completionHandle: (Bool, [T]?) -> ()) {
        completionHandle(true, self.structs)
    }
}
```

This ensures that `structs` contains elements of the same type expected by the `action` method.

Comment: Thank you very much! Actually, I have used the second solution you post before asking the question. However, since I use the `AProtocol` as an interface data structure, I'd like to put a constraint on the type `T` to ensure everything communicate with `AProtocol`. So I tried your first solution and it works like a charm! I would mark your answer as accepted if I could mark both. I vote for it. Thanks again!